# SQL - where (value1,value2) in list of lists

Tags: sql

Table

```
- id, :x,y
 - 1   : 1    1
 - 2   : 1   2
 - 3   : 1   3
 - 4   : 2   1
 - 5   : 2   2
 - 6   : 2   2
```

I want to SELECT id from input list of lists ((1,1),(1,3),(2,2),...)

(actually a lot bigger list (~14k lists of (x,y) pairs))

Expected results: id-s: 1,3,5

Bad solution i tried: "where x in (1,2) and y in (1,2,3)"

returned all 6 rows

Any help welcome. First question asked, feedback welcome.

Edit1: The list and data is a lot bigger. Made it smaller to explain myself more easier

Edit2: where (x,y) in ((1,2),....) worked for me

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to *accept* an answer (by selecting the checkmark button to the left of the answer that solved your problem), *not* by editing your question's title. See [what should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Got it Damien. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of optimization, it is often best to put the "constant" list in a temporary table and use a join.  In many databases, this would look like:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select 1 as x, 1 as y union all select 1, 3 union all select 2, 2
     ) list
     on t.x = list.x and t.y = list.y;
```

Database optimizers often work better on joins than on complicated `where` clauses.

Some databases will also support a `where` clause like this:

```
where (x, y) in ((1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2))
```

Of course, you can always use the sequence of comparisons suggested by Juergen, which works in any database.

Comment: Thanks!
    where (x, y) in ((1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2))

Did the trick for me