# Subquery as Element of Nested SQL List

Tags: sql, r, nested, subquery, sql-injection

## TLDR

Is there a dialect of SQL that not only (1) permits nested lists, but also (2) permits an SQL subquery be a valid element of such a list?

```
SELECT *
FROM tuples
WHERE (dim_1, dim_2) IN ((1, 2), (SELECT DISTINCT x, y FROM coords LIMIT 2))
```

## Background

Sorry to post an academic question due to my narrow domain knowledge, rather than a diagnostic question due to code errors. I post this question here because I have been unable to find an answer online: most search results deal with nested *subqueries*, and any others deal with nested lists containing *scalar* elements.

I am writing an R function `insert_params()` to dynamically create an SQL list from an arbitrary R `list()` (via `DBI::sqlInterpolate()` to prevent injection), with optional recursion (or alternatively flattening via `unlist()`) for nested lists. I have in mind a situation like

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE (field_1, field_2) IN (('bobby', 'tables'), ('strawberry', 'fields'), (SELECT 0 WHERE 0 = 1))
```

where `insert_params()` is designed to (optionally) insert an empty subquery as a syntactically valid representation in SQL (as opposed to `()`) of an empty `list()` from R.

While I am working for the moment with Microsoft SQL Server, which does not seem to permit nested SQL lists, I don't want `insert_params()` to limit users working with other SQL dialects, so I want to build in the flexibility to handle nested lists.

Now `insert_params()` does indeed produce an SQL string like the one above, as intended.  However, I want to ensure this string is syntactically valid in those SQL dialects that do permit nested lists; otherwise, this functionality is pointless.

Thanks for your help!

### Edit:

I'd also like to know if such dialects (if they exist) and queries pose issues for ANSI compliance.  I don't know much about ANSI compliance, but `insert_params()` does use a `DBI::ANSI` object in tandem with `DBI::sqlInterpolate()`.  Per R documentation for `DBI::ANSI`:

> **Description**
>
> A dummy DBI connector that simulates ANSI-SQL compliance

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm

Comment: My suggestion: insert a temporary table with just field1 and field2, then inner-join `my_table` with this on those two fields being equal. I might be missing a point about your last `select 0...`, but perhaps this will work for you.

Comment: Then your problem migrates to a different one: how to identify temporary tables in different dialects of SQL. For instance, SQL Server requires prepending with `#` instead of using `create temporary table ...`, for which `DBI::dbWriteTable(..., temporary=FALSE)` *fails*. Many DBA will curse you if you do not keep your temporary tables *temporary*, so ... good luck :-)

Comment: Hi @Serg, thanks for the link!  I am not well versed in graphic syntax diagrams, so should I assume that a subquery does not qualify as an expression, and thus cannot be nested within an expression list?  If so, does this disqualification apply to _every_ single dialect of SQL?

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thanks for the advice!  I have seen `JOIN`s suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367569/sql-where-value1-value2-in-list-of-lists) as a solution to a statically defined list of lists. However, the goal of my `insert_params()` function is to accept a dynamic R `list()` and [interpolate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/sqlInterpolate) it as a variable `my_list` into an SQL string in place of a placeholder: `WHERE (field_1, field_2) IN ?my_list` becomes `WHERE (field_1, field_2) IN (('bobby', 'tables'), ...)`.

Comment: My apologies, @r2evans. I accidentally submitted the above comment before it was complete, so I might have edited it to add the important clarification after you last read it.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can handle this in one of two ways.  I would recommend:

```
WHERE (dim_1, dim_2) IN ((1, 2)) OR
      (dim_1, dim_2) IN (SELECT x, y FROM coords LIMIT 2))
```

Or:

```
WHERE (dim_1, dim_2) IN ( (SELECT x, y FROM coords LIMIT 2) 
                          UNION ALL
                          (SELECT 1, 2)
                        )
```

Notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed with `IN`.
- `LIMIT` is not standard SQL.  The generic SQL would be `FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY`.
- Not all databases support `SELECT` with no `FROM`, so the second solution would need to be tweaked in those databases.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff!  Unfortunately, `insert_params()` needs to be fully dynamic, for an R `list()` of arbitrary size. 
Since it is intended to extrapolate the functionality of [`DBI::sqlInterpolate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/sqlInterpolate) to parameters that are `list()` objects in R, it can modify only one section of the SQL string, namely the placeholder `my_list` in the string `WHERE (dim_1, dim_2) IN ?my_list`.

Comment: Perhaps there is no good way to map an empty nested `list()` from R to the functional equivalent of an empty list (nested within another list) in SQL: that is, an SQL list in which no value will return `TRUE` when tested (with `IN`) for membership in that list.  Even if we're just mapping functional "emptiness" for the outermost R `list()`, by using an empty SQL subquery in `WHERE (dim_1, dim_2) IN (SELECT 0 WHERE 0 = 1)`, there's still the challenge of defining a "universal empty subquery" that functions across all dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the feature, for example, this is a valid Oracle SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (a, b) IN (((select max(a) from mytable), (select max(b) from mytable)), (9,5));
```

Note subqueries at the `IN` list of tuples.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7cf21fbbdfc6e33d5bd3d2793d98f78)

and this is valid query too

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (a, b) IN (
    select a+1, b+1 from mytable union all
    select 9,5 from dual union all
    select (select max(a) from mytable), (select max(b) from mytable) from dual)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Serg! I take it this is valid for only scalar subqueries, and not for empty or multi-valued subqueries.

Comment: Oops!  Saw your edit only after I had already commented.